# sharepoint 3.0 Project tasks list - showing dependent tasks and linking betweekn taks

Tags: task-list

Is there any option to show link between tasks and dependency between tasks in gantt chart.Please let me know is it possible with Sharepoint services 3.0?
Or is there any webparts which fulfills my requirement

Thanks in advance